# exclude an item from the list using python

Tags: python-2.7

```
import os
file_dir_path = "D:/Test/list"
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(file_dir_path):
  if fileList != []:
    jpg_name = fileList[0]
    if jpg_name!='Thumbs.db':
      continue
```

Result for fileList : ['Rope01.jpg','Rope02.jpg','Thumbs.db']

In the fileList, I want to exclude that Thumbs.db to be listed.

Comment: It seems that you want just jpeg's, right?

Comment: `fileList = [x for x in fileList if x != 'Thumbs.db']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fileList` is the list of the files that `os.walk` returns for each directory it traverses.

You just have to filter out your .db filename:

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(file_dir_path):
    fileList = [x for x in fileList if x != 'Thumbs.db']
    # now fileList contains everything in dirName but Thumbs.db
```